# Why Images from secure url are not visible in Magento?

Tags: apache, magento

I am developing a Magento site.The url of the site is like http://www.xyz.com/index.php/

But some of the images are coming from secure url
https://www.xyz.com/skin/frontend/default/mytheme/images/logo.png

The images which are having https:// are not visible in the frontend.

Till yesterday the site was working well and images were not coming from https:// url. I think at client side they done some changes and problem arise. How to find the cause of problem.

[image]

I get something like that in browser.

[image]

Comment: Check if the SSL certificate has expired or has any issues.  Try this:
http://www.digicert.com/help/

Comment: What does your browser's element inspector's "net" tab say about what happens to the images?